# Can I have explosive impulse responses from stable VAR?

Tags: stationarity, vector-autoregression

Say I have VAR(p) process written in VAR(1) form (companion form),

$Y_t = v + AY_{t-1} + \epsilon$

I am checking the stability by making sure that all the eigenvalues of A are inside the unit circle. My question is that, even when the stability condition as defined above holds, is it possible to have exploding impulse responses, i.e., those that does not revert to zero?

Answer (score 1):

If all eigenvalues are inside the unit circle, and the system is in that sense stable, then your can write the series expansion of the reduced form inverse (sorry if my terminology is not correct) to see you can expect it to converge.

Error terms can, of course, potentially do whatever. But given the usual assumptions and looking at the pure impulse response, the limited spectral radius of $A$ implies that the series will converge and not diverge chaotically.
If it converges to zero or not depends of course on the matrix $A$ and $v$, but I take your question to be about exploding impulse responses.